# converse of Lagrange theorem in algebra

Tags: group-theory

I'm looking for the finite groups (for example n elements) that have subgroups with every divisor of n elements.
Say a simple example is cyclic groups.
Please help me to find more and more groups with this condition.

Comment: This is true for abelian groups: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477500/showing-that-a-finite-abelian-group-has-a-subgroup-of-order-m-for-each-divisor-m

Comment: Should be converse, not inverse.

Comment: Finite $p$-groups for any prime $p$.

Comment: And dihedral groups should work fine too. Moreover, if $G,H$ satisfy the desired property, $G\times H$ too...

Answer (score 6):

A seminal paper on the subject, "A note on CLT groups", was written by [Henry Bray](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=56) and appeared in the [Pacific J. of Mathematics Vol. 27, No. 2, 1968](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102983900). The paper can be downloaded as a pdf file for free. It is easy to read.

Comment: I added the title of the paper as it complements the answer of AnalysisStudent0414. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, thanks, good addition!

Answer (score 4):

I have seen a (finite) group with this property being called **CLT group** (Converse Lagrange Theorem group).

It is relatively easy to see that abelian groups and $p$-groups both satisfy this property.

[Here](https://seewoo5.wordpress.com/2016/10/24/clt-group/) it is shown that every nilpotent group is CLT (so, in particular, every abelian group is CLT). The proof is based on the well-known characterization of finite nilpotent groups as direct products of their Sylow subgroups (which are CLT).

Even more generally, [here](https://msp.org/pjm/1968/27-2/pjm-v27-n2-p02-p.pdf) the author proves that every supersolvable group is CLT, and shows a solvable group which is not $(A_4)$.